# How should I organize two objects in order to be able to join them on a key?

Tags: c#, xml

So basically, I am reading in two XML docs. The first has two values that need to be stored: Name and Value. The second has four values: Name, DefaultValue, Type, and Limit. When reading in the docs, I want to store each into some object. I need to be able to then combine the two objects into one that has 5 values stored in it. The XML docs are different lengths, but the second will always be AT LEAST the size of the first.

EXAMPLE:

```
<XML1>
  <Item1>
    <Name>Cust_No</Name>
    <Value>10001</Value>
  </Item1>
  <Item4>
    ITEM4 NAME AND VALUE
  </Item4>
  <Item7>
    ITEM 7 NAME AND VALUE
  </Item7>
</XML1>

<XML2>
  <Item1>
    <Name>Cust_No</Name>
    <DefaultValue></DefaultValue>
    <Type>varchar</Type>
    <Limit>15</Limit>
  </Item1>
  6 MORE TIMES ITEMS 2-7
</XML2>
```

I already have code looping through the XML. I really just need thoughts on what the best way to store the data it. Ultimately, I want to be able to join the two objects on the Name Key. I tried `string[]` and `arrayList[]`, but I ran into difficulty combining them. I also read up on the `Dictionary`, but had trouble implementing that, too (I've never used the `Dictionary` before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Linq to Xml query, which will join two XDocuments and select anonymous objects for joined items. Each object will have five properties:

```
var query = 
  from i1 in xdoc1.Root.Elements()
  join i2 in xdoc2.Root.Elements()
      on (string)i1.Element("Name") equals (string)i2.Element("Name") into g
  let j = g.SingleOrDefault() // get joined element from second file, if any
  select new {
      Name = g.Key,
      Value = (int)i1.Element("Value"),
      DefaultValue = (j == null) ? null : (string)j.Element("DefaultValue"),
      Type = (j == null) ? null : (string)j.Element("Type"),
      Limit = (j == null) ? null : (string)j.Element("Limit")
  };
```

XDocuments created like this:

```
var xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml1);
var xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml2);
```

Usage of query:

```
foreach(var item in query)
{
   // use string item.Name
   // integer item.Value
   // string item.DefaultValue
   // string item.Type
   // string item.Limit
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great. But how do I access the data now? What is it stored in?